# How to programmatically send MMS without intent

Tags: android, mms

I have an application that can send MMS programmatically without resorting to any third party applications using intents that works in ICS. However, JB onwards the application fails to send MMS because it cannot get hold of APNs.
In particular, I use the following command to get the APNS for the phone:

```
List<APN> apns = cr.query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), null, null, null, null);
```

This request fails with following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings:  android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.
```

This happens only on JB onwards. What is the workaround to get carrier's MMS APN information.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no public API for achieve this task.There are no APIs exposed by Android to send an MMS.If you want to send MMS then you have to write code.Please refer the AOSP code. https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms OR you can use Intent and then launch the native Messaging App.

Comment: This uses permission WRITE_APN_SETTINGS which is "Not for use by third-party applications". The app I need to write is not a system app.
I see some non-system applications like Handcent, Textra that can send and receive MMS. How are they written?

Comment: @user2995358 I would imagine they guess what the APN settings are based on the carrier name and then have an option to manually override their guess if it isn't working.